# 403 Error - Forbidden error on making curl request

Tags: php, apache, curl, http-status-code-403

I have two virtual hosts, xyz.com and abc.com. From xyz.com I'm making curl post call(using PHP) to http://abc.com/test
This returns me "403 Error - Forbidden" (http://abc.com/test works fine in browser)

I know this questions sounds quite repeating one. Sorry about that, as I have went through all the solutions given in previous answers, nothing works :-(

1. My root folders (doc root) in Apache, have 775 permissions.
2. In httpd.conf my controls are as follows

   ```
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   ```
3. I have also tried adding USERAGENT (of firefox) in code to emulate browser.

I'm not getting whats the exact problem here with Apache. I'm using Apache 2.4

Can some please work out to help on this?

**UPDATED**
Below is code which I'm using for sending request.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://abc.com/test');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'a=b&c=d&e=f');
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Add your code too to get answers faster.

Comment: Which code? http://abc.com/test or Code using which I'm sending curl request ? (I guess, problem seems with Apache)

Comment: Could it be one of the headers?

Comment: May be.. I could not figure out exactly which code. Perhaps, I have updated question with code using which I'm sending curl call.

Comment: you don't need to add the content-type header, curl does that automatically with curlopt_post being true.

Comment: I tried it, removing HTTP HEADER doesn't help. Still I get the same forbidden 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, its solved. Just changed:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```